# $state.go not working to go back for the first view with ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

hey everybody i have a problem, I can move normaly from one view to another, but when i get to one and want to go back to the first view of the project it simply don't go.

my app.js

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
$stateProvider

.state('game', {
    url: "/game",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/game.html"
})

.state('game.begin', {
    url: '/begin',
    views: {
      'begin': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/begin.html',
        controller: 'BeginCtrl'
      }
    }
})
.state('game.match', {
    url: '/match/:fileWithQuestions',
    views: {
      'match': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/match.html',
        controller: 'MatchCtrl'
      }
    }
})
.state('game.result', {
    url: '/result',
    views: {
      'result': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/result.html',
        controller: 'ResultCtrl'
      }
    }
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/game/begin');
})
```

the place I call the page that the problem is.

```
function countDown() {
    myTymeOut = $timeout(countDown, 1000);
    $scope.counter--;
    if($scope.counter === 0) {
        $timeout.cancel(myTymeOut);
        SendArray.sendData(answeredWords);
        releaseMidias();
        $state.go('^.result');
    }
    navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

the controller where the problem is:

```
controller.controller('ResultCtrl', function($scope, $state, $timeout, SendArray) {
screen.lockOrientation('portrait');

$scope.array = SendArray.getData();

$scope.back = function() {
    $state.go('^.begin');
}

});
```

the html where the back funciton is called

```
<ion-nav-view name="result">
<ion-view title="result">
    <ion-pane>
        <div class="back_div">
            <a ng-click="back()">
                <img src="img/result/voltar.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="item in array">
            <h1 ng-if="item.answer == true">{{item.word}}</h1>
            <h1 ng-if="item.answer == false" style="color: red;">{{item.word}}</h1>
        </div>
    </ion-pane>
</ion-view>
```

the function is called i've already tried with alerts, and the state.go gives me an object, but it doesn't redirect the page...

Comment: when you use abstract=true in the parent controllers or say in main url.. you whole page loads only when its all child states are resolved.. here you are calling the child instance?I have never tried this before though? Have you tried using $location.path('/begin');

Comment: im gonna try just a sec

Comment: im new at this, should i remove the abstract from game?

Answer (score 0):

I found out somewhere that you have to disable `$ionicHistory` before going back to home.

```
.controller('someCtrl', function($scope, $state ,$ionicHistory) {
   $scope.backFunction = function() {
     $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
          disableBack: true
     });
     $state.go('^.home');
   };
});
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.